# Doctrine One To Many add column check

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two Entities

User

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $birthDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="location_country", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $locationCountry;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="location_city", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $locationCity;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column( type="text", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $avatar;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="wall_image", type="text", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $wallImage;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column( type="text", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $about;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Follower", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $followers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Follower", mappedBy="follower")
     */
    protected $followings;

    /**
     * Is followed. Used when checking is followed by another user.
     */
    protected $isFollowed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="user")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $photos;

    public function getFirstName()
    {
    return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
    return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
    return $this->phone;
    }

    public function getBirthDate()
    {
    return $this->birthDate;
    }

    public function getGender()
    {
    return $this->gender;
    }

    public function getLocationCountry()
    {
    return $this->locationCountry;
    }

    public function getLocationCity()
    {
    return $this->locationCity;
    }

    public function getAvatar()
    {
    return $this->avatar;
    }

    public function getAvatarImage()
    {
    return $this->getAvatarPath().$this->avatar;
    }

    public function getWallImage()
    {
    return $this->wallImage;
    }

    public function getAbout()
    {
    return $this->about;
    }

    public function getAvatarPath()
    {
        return '/web/uploads/avatars/'.$this->id.'/';
    }

    public function getWallImagePath()
    {
        return '/web/uploads/wall/'.$this->id.'/';
    }

    public function getFollowers()
    {
        return $this->followers;
    }

    public function getFollowings()
    {
        return $this->followings;
    }

    public function getFollowersCount()
    {
        //print_r($this->followers->toArray());
    }

    public function getPhotos()
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    public function isFollowed()
    {
        return $this->isFollowed;
    }

    public function setFirstName($value)
    {
    $this->firstName = $value;
    }

    public function setLastName($value)
    {
    $this->lastName = $value;
    }

    public function setPhone($value)
    {
    $this->phone = $value;
    }

    public function setBirthDate($value)
    {
    $this->birthDate = $value;
    }

    public function setGender($value)
    {
    $this->gender = $value;
    }

    public function setLocationCountry($value)
    {
    $this->locationCountry = $value;
    }

    public function setLocationCity($value)
    {
    $this->locationCity = $value;
    }

    public function setAvatar($path)
    {
    $this->avatar = $path;
    }

    public function setWallImage($path)
    {
    $this->wallImage = $path;
    }

    public function setAbout($about)
    {
    $this->about = $about;
    }

    public function setFollowed($isFollowed)
    {
    $this->isFollowed = $isFollowed;
    }
}
```

Photo

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="photos")
 */
class Photo
{
    const
            CATEGORY_PHOTOGRAPHY = 1,
            CATEGORY_PAINTING = 2,
            CATEGORY_3D = 3;

    /*
     * Flow photos limit
     */
    const FLOW_PHOTOS_LIMIT = 15;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="photos")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PhotoCategory")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $creationDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="edit_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $editDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_moderated", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isModerated = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isActive = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="photo")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $comments;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return Photo
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return User $user
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return Category $category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Photo
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Get creationDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Get editDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEditDate()
    {
        return $this->editDate;
    }

    /**
     * Get is active
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Get is moderated
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function isModerated()
    {
        return $this->isModerated;
    }

    /*
     * Get image
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->getWebDirectory().$this->getName();
    }

    /*
     * Get image directory 
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDirectory()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/uploads/photos/'.$this->getUser()->getId().'/'.$this->creationDate->format('Y-m-d').'/';
    }

    /*
     * Get image web directory
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWebDirectory()
    {
        return '/web/uploads/photos/'.$this->getUser()->getId().'/'.$this->creationDate->format('Y-m-d').'/';
    }

    /*
     * Get comments
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Photo
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Photo
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set creationDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $creationDate
     */
    public function setCreationDate(\DateTime $creationDate)
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set editDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $editDate
     */
    public function setEditDate(\DateTime $editDate)
    {
        $this->editDate = $editDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->isActive = $active;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    /**
     * Set moderated
     */
    public function setModerated($moderated)
    {
        $this->isModerated = $moderated;
    }
}
```

As you see, i have isActive in Photo, which is telling is photo deleted or not. So, i get all users photos via User->getPhotos() which is one-to-many. But it return all users photos. How should be done, so it returns all photos which have isActive = true?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this.

Cosmin provided one for you, which will result in Doctrine loading each photo, and then PHP code checking to see whether or not it is active.  This will work in the most number of situations, but will potentially be slow inefficient.

Yet another solution, is to use "criteria":

```
$exp = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr();
$activePhotos = $user->getPhotos()->matching(
    new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria(
        $exp->eq('active', true)
    )
);
```

This will do something similar to the `filter` that Cosmin suggested, but allow for Doctrine to filter at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the filter method to query inside entities

```
$user->getPhotos()->filter(
    function($photo) {
       return $photo->isActive();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method inside the User entity, using the code of @Cosmin Ordean :) Something like this

```
public function getActivePhotos() {
     return $this->getPhotos()->filter(
        function($photo) {
           return $photo->isActive();
        }
     );
}
```